# Getting two values from a Vue <select> @change event

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down `<select>` element that uses an array with key:value pairs. I'd like for the dropdown to only display values, but upon selection have the @change pass on both the value and the key.

```
<select
  @change="
    formChanged(
      $event,
      $event.target.selectedIndex,
      $event.target.value,
      $event.target.key
    )
  "
  name="selectForm"
  id="selectForm"
  required
>
  <option
    v-for="(option, id) in getFormSelectArray()"
    :key="id" :value="option"
  >
    {{ option }}
  </option>
</select>
```

My function called through @change:

```
  formChanged(event, selectedIndex, value, id): void {
    console.log(
      'Form Selection Changed: ' + event + '  ' + selectedIndex + ' ' + value, + ' ' + id
    );
  }
```

My data array generating function:

```
public getFormSelectArray() {
// Mapping IDs to Names
const names = 'a, b, c';
const ids = '123, 456, 789';
let i;
let currentKey;
let currentVal;

const result = {}

for (i = 0; i < ids.split(',').length; i++) {
    currentKey = ids.split(',')[i];
    currentVal = names.split(',')[i];
    result[currentKey] = currentVal; 
}

for (const key in result) {
    const value = result[key];
}
   
      return result;
}
```

My output:

```
Form Selection Changed: [object Event]  0 a NaN
```

How do I output the ID of 123 instead of NaN?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@input` instead of `@change`.